# How do I produce functional dependencies and corresponding relations from a case study?

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization, database-normalization

I need some help with a project I'm doing. I need to clarify the meaning of some of the requirements which I don't get at all. The bold parts are the ones causing me trouble.

I've got a case study, and there are requirements like "create the Entity Relationship diagram", etc. One of the requirements says"

- **Produce** the functional dependencies, and,
- **using normalization, a set of corresponding relations** for each of the manual records

By the manual records, it means some records that were supposedly filled manually before implementing the system.

Does anyone know what should I create or do with this?, does it ask me for some sort of diagram?.

Then, on another requirement, it says: "**combine the sets of relations to produce an overall set of relations(tables)** in third normal form" and it also tells me to ensure the relations are consistent with my Entity relationship diagram. So, does anyone know what is asking me to do?

Comment: Which of those things do you know how to do (and what they mean)? Do you need help with *all* of it, including terms like "entity-relationship diagram" and "third normal form" or just the bolded parts? It's not quite clear.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, John, just with the bolded parts, I have no idea what kind of thing it wants me to do when it says that, it isn't clear.

Comment: What's the context for this question? At the point you'd get this kind of assignment in say, a database design class, you should already know at least generally what's being asked for here. "Producing" the functional dependencies is just asking you to pull the FD's out from the information about the data being modeled and the constraints (and maybe to use inference axioms to infer more). You seem to be familiar with concepts like 3NF and ER diagrams, so I'd assume you already know how you're expected to present relations.

Comment: Thanks again John, I get the functional dependencies part, what I don't get at all if what the problem wants when it says "using normalization (produce) a set of corresponding relations" for each manual record, what would a "set of corresponding relation" be for you?, it's confusing because it then asks me to "combine the sets of relations to produce an overall set of relation (tables) in third normal form" I've been trying to understand what should I use to represent that "set of relations", any ideas of what could it be?. I'm sorry I can't even explain it. Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: When these directions say "manual records," are they divided into groups somehow, or do you maybe have one of each of several types of record? Posting more of the problem might help, but after the FDs, just a list of relations with their keys/attributes seems to be what's called for.

Comment: There are three manual records being used (manual record as in a piece of paper the employees use), each of these manual records combine attributes from different tables, for example, there's one manual record that has details of the animals at the top, in the middle it has details of where the manual is held (temperature, humidity, etc) and finally, at the bottom we have notes taken by employees observing the animal (like, temperature of the animal, weight, date and time when the data was recorded, etc).

Comment: All of these are in different tables inside the database, and that's when it somehow asks me to show the relations, it doesn't want a ERD, it just want the "set of relations", and then an overall set of relations (again) for the three manual records, first a set of relations for each manual record, and the the three together. I hope this makes sense and it helps clarify the whole situation a bit. You have no idea how grateful I am, you're the only one taking his time to answer me, so thank you very much again.

Answer (score 2):

"Producing" the functional dependencies requires knowledge of the business domain.

As an IT systems designer, you will always need input from the business side before you can successfully do this task.  What is the business-side input that is available to you ?